# how to make bot be able to show link for any emoji from any server

Tags: discord.py

so this command works and all but...

```
    @commands.command()
    async def se(self, ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji):
        await ctx.send(f"**Name:**Illdo this later **Link:**{emoji.url}")
```

it only works for the emojis from the server that the bot is in.
does anyone know how to make it be able to get the link for any servers emojis? even if the bot isnt in it
and if you wanna, also i need help with the showing the name of the emoji

the kind of thing i am going for is

[image]
thank you!

Comment: And how do you want the emoji to be showed, does someone execute a command to save it, or do you want to save all of the guild's custom emojis?

Comment: Wouldn't it be impossible anyway? The bot needs to be in the same server to get an emoji at all, so this would be *impossible*. Is the image provided from another bot, or did you create that image?

Comment: Nope, we can directly use the emoji id, to get the image from cdn

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the id of the emoji and make the url itself

You can get its `id` by some `split()` and also you need to check if its animated so we can use `.gif` and `.png` accordingly

Below is the code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def se(self, ctx, *, msg):
    _id = msg.split(":") # split by ":"
    if "<a" == _id[0]: # animated emojis structure <a:name:id>
        ext = "gif"
    else:
        ext = "png" # normal emojis structure <name:id>
    e_id = _id[2].split(">")[0].strip()# get the id
    # url for a emoji is like this, try yourself if you want to check by manually copying any emoji's url
    url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/{e_id}.{ext}"
    await ctx.send(f"**Name**: :{_id[1]}: **Link**: {url}")
```